# Error install PyGtk

Tags: python, pygtk

I tried to install pygtk on mac. I downloaded the pygtk file, opened up terminal and set it to my working directory, then ran the command "python setup.py install". There was an import error because there was no module dsextras. Does anyone know how to install pygtk on a mac or get dsextras.

Comment: Install PyGObject for dsextras

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PyGtk is a beast to install because has many dependencies (see [this](http://buffalothedestroyer.blogspot.com/2009/07/blog-post.html) post).
I recommend you to install pyGtk using [macports](http://www.macports.org/), it will handle dependencies hell for you.